Is there anywhere a list of the groups $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)/\mathbb{Q})$?
As a math undegraduate, I was doing my homework of fields and Galois theory course and observed that many questions asked us to calculate the group  $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\xi_n)/\mathbb{Q})$, where $\xi_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of the unit (so, to say if it is isomorphic to $D_4$, to $C_2\times C_2\times C_3$, ... Or whatsoever...)
So, I imagine that such a thing so cannonical must be already classified, maybe not for every $n$, but for quite many of them. And I wondered if there would be any resource with a full classification of this kind of Galois groups. Or maybe there is a  simple method common to all of them.
I have the feeling that this will have to do with cyclotomic extensions, but we have not yet covered those on my course.

Wikipedia wrote: The Galois group ${\displaystyle \operatorname {Gal} (\mathbf {Q} (\zeta _{n})/\mathbf {Q} )}$ is naturally isomorphic to the multiplicative group ${\displaystyle (\mathbf {Z} /n\mathbf {Z} )^{\times }}$

@hbghlyj What page?

Cyclotomic field

@hbghlyj Ok, nice, I know how to compute on those groups, but what are there isomorphic to in terms of the groups we normally refer to (in general)?

in Wikipedia: Multiplicative group of integers modulo n

@hbghlyj Now the question is answered : ) Thanks
